# Excel-If case copy paste from another sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, vba

I have a workbook which has 2 sheets.(Roles and roleUpdates). Role update sheet contains the role changes and new roles. It has more entry than the Roles sheet but I only want to deal with the entries that is both in the Roles and RoleUpdates. One of the colums in the RoleUpdates is called "status" and one of the options is roleChange. Roles sheet is the one that I want to update which has the older roles. Basically I want to look at the status column in the RoleUpdates and if it is "roleChange", then I want to copy that role column in the RoleUpdates sheet and paste it into Roles sheet based on the name. Example;

```
roleUpdates Sheet

COL A       COL B     COL C 
ROLES       NAMES     STATUS   
Teller      David     roleChange   
Customer    Tom       noChange 
Admin      Liam      roleChange
-------------


    Before Running Macro
Roles Sheet
    ------------- 
COL A       COL B 
ROLES       NAMES 
Customer    Liam 
Admin       David  
Teller      Tom
    -------------


After Running Macro
Roles Sheet
    ------------- 
COL A       COL B 
ROLES       NAMES 
Admin       Liam 
Teller      David  
Customer    Tom
    -------------
```

I hope this was clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to clean up your example up top, it makes no sense. You have Tom showing as a customer with no change up top, then in the next example you have him as a teller switching to a customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks the status column, then if it's a rolechange, looks for the name on the other sheet and brings the new value in from the roleUpdates sheet.

```
Sub ChangesRoles()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("roleUpdates")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("roleUpdates").Range("C" & i).Value = "roleChange" Then
        For j = 2 To lastrow
            If Worksheets("Roles Sheet").Range("B" & j).Value = Worksheets("roleUpdates").Range("B" & i).Value Then
                Worksheets("Roles Sheet").Range("A" & j).Value = Worksheets("roleUpdates").Range("A" & i).Value
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: BeforeAfter]